# How to retrieve data from azure table storage between date and time

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to retrieve data between 2 dates from table storage using logdatetime column in my table, i end up getting this

> {"Result":[],"Id":11,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"IsCompletedSuccessfully":true,"CreationOptions":0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}

instead of data between those 2 days. FYI id hardcoded, from datetime and to datetime.

```
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();              

            string partitionFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "partitionkey");

            string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                                    TableQuery.CombineFilters(partitionFilter, TableOperators.And, "logdatetime eq datetime'2019-03-17T19:09:26.0000000Z'"), TableOperators.And, "logdatetime eq datetime'2019-03-17T19:10:16.0000000Z'");

            var query = new TableQuery<TelemetryData>().Where(finalFilter);
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TableName");
            var result = table.EndExecuteQuerySegmented(query,null);
```

Comment: i believe the query is wrong, you should be using logdatetime ge datetime'2019-03-17T19:09:26.0000000Z' and logdatetime le datetime'2019-03-17T19:10:16.0000000Z' to get the range between those datetimes there is no way a datetime can be equal to two different datetimes

Comment: How many records you will have for this filter? because your query could be slow

Comment: Thank you it worked when changed to ge/le

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get results between two datetime, you should use the operators `le / ge` in the query filter.

So you should change the operator `eq` to `le or ge` respectively in the following code:

```
string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                                    TableQuery.CombineFilters(partitionFilter, TableOperators.And, "logdatetime ge datetime'2019-03-17T19:09:26.0000000Z'"), TableOperators.And, "logdatetime le datetime'2019-03-17T19:10:16.0000000Z'");
```